# What are these panels for?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

Go to menu `Window > Show View > Other... > Debug > Display (and Registers)`

These panels `Display` and `Registers`, what are they for and how to use them?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those eclipse views are not supported for flex.

Registers view is for C++ and it shows processor's registers(which is absolutely meaningless for flex).

Display view is for Java debugging, it is not activated during flex debugging.

Here are links to their descriptions:

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fdisplay%2Fref-display_view.htm

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fdisplay%2Fref-display_view.htm